# How to change jquery animate() duration while animating using step

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

So here is the scenario. I'm trying to make a infinite image carousel, and everytime it will show an image that has a class of special `.special` I want to slow down the animation duration or the scrolling of the animation. So users can see the **special image**   longer. Here is my code.

```
$photoGalleryList.animate({
    left :  '-' + (computedWidth) + 'px'
}, 
{
    duration : 10000,
    easing : 'linear',
    step : function(now, fx) {
        if(visibleSpecialImage()) {
             // SLOW ANIMATION DURATION
             // Tried setting fx.options.duration still no effect
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if my approach is right **(doing it with step)**, jquery animate() documentation [says](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> **step**
> Type: Function( Number **now**, Tween **tween** )
>
> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated element. This function  provides an opportunity to modify the Tween object to change the value of the property before it is set.

I'm not sure if I understood the documentation clearly, But base on what I read it's possible using step, I tried googling my problem and never found any concrete answer So now I'm **stackoverflowing** and hopefully solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a animation function and pass a `special` duration for only special type images instead?

Comment: @kayen worst case that's what I'm gonna do. I just want to know if I can achieve my desired result using jquery animate().